# Pasar de array a objeto sin usar los métodos de Object (values, keys y entries)

Tags: javascript

En este ejercicio, quiero pasar este array: `[ 'Fulano', 'nombre', 'Rodriguez', 'apellido' ]` a objeto y que quede así: `{ Fulano: "nombre", Rodriguez: "apellido" }` , sin utilizar los métodos de Object (values, keys y entries).

Hasta ahora, mi código es este:

```
  var nuevoObjeto = [ 'Fulano', 'nombre', 'Rodriguez', 'apellido' ]
 
 var obj = nuevoObjeto.reduce(function(acm,ele){
    acm[ele] = ele
    return acm
},{})

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

El metodo reduce hace un barrido elemento por elemento, por lo que es mejor ver otro camino. Una solucion puede ser con un for, aumentando en 2 su valor en cada iteracion. Suponiendo que la estructura siempre es [llave, valor, llave, valor] quedaría como la siguiente:

```
var nuevoObjeto = [ 'Fulano', 'nombre', 'Rodriguez', 'apellido' ]
let obj = {}
for(i = 0; i<nuevoObjeto.length - 1; i+=2){ 
     obj[nuevoObjeto[i]] = nuevoObjeto[i+1];  
}
        
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Excelente! Muchas gracias!